# new_path url is showing correctly in address bar but displaying a different page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a problem where my link to orders#new is bringing up the right url in the browser but is rendering what looks like orders#index but with no entries in it.

Here are my routes, I'm wondering if I've got a problem with the priorities in them?

```
  get 'loans/stock' => 'loans#stock'
  resources :loans
  get 'parts/all' => 'parts#view', :as => :parts_all
  get 'orders/:region' => 'orders#region', :as => :orders_by_region
  get 'orders/:printer/parts' => 'orders#printerparts', :as => :parts_by_printer
  resources :orders do
    resources :parts
  end
  resources :parts
```

EDIT
I've taken the below advice and resorted my routes but it seems whatever I do something breaks. I have a link for my orders filtering by region and the filter to show parts belonging to an order by it's printer.

If I move the region route down it stops working. If I leave it where it is, the new and show actions won't work for orders. Maybe I've just done something completely wrong in my setup?

```
  get 'loans/stock' => 'loans#stock'
  resources :loans
  get 'parts/all' => 'parts#view', :as => :parts_all
  get 'orders/:printer/parts' => 'orders#printerparts', :as => :parts_by_printer
  get 'orders/new' => 'orders#new', :as => :a_new_order
  resources :orders do
    resources :parts
  end
  resources :parts
  get 'orders/:region' => 'orders#region', :as => :orders_by_region
```

So these are my routes now. This makes the 'orders/:printer/parts' link work, and I can add new orders and get to the show page of existing ones. However the orders by region link now doesn't work, it throws a 'no id found' active record error.

Comment: It looks like it will be processed by `region` action, if we are talking about `orders/new` url. This should be in your logs by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you should give your `orders#region` route lower priority, as it overrules `orders#new`:

```
get 'loans/stock' => 'loans#stock'
resources :loans
get 'parts/all' => 'parts#view', :as => :parts_all
resources :orders do
  resources :parts
end
resources :parts
get 'orders/:region' => 'orders#region', :as => :orders_by_region
get 'orders/:printer/parts' => 'orders#printerparts', :as => :parts_by_printer
```

You might as well consider giving your `#region` and `#printer` routes constraints on naming, for example:

```
get 'orders/:region', to: 'orders#region', region: /[a-z]{5}/, as: :orders_by_region
```

(Modified example from [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints))

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. My regions and printers are set up in the seeds so I'm happy with those. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: You are welcome. If you like the answer, you might upvote as well :)

Comment: I will do as soon as I hit 15 the rep (bit of a newbie). Would you mind having a look at the edit I added above? It seems solving one problem has given a new one!

Comment: Sure. Just please post the exact error message or the exact result you didn't expect.

Comment: You should add constaint, so that your `orders/:region` doesn't interfere with `orders/:id` (i.e. `OrdersController#show`). Does your region contain only letters? Or letters and numbers? Does it at least always *start* with letter?

Comment: That was it, I just had to change the route name so that it stopped getting interrupted. Thanks for all your help, it's really appreciated